# Visual Studio Thread Statement gives Error?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lua, code-injection

I decompiled a .NET Application to write my own Injection Software. A Thread Error don't want to get removed. I tried everything but it keeps telling me that something is wrong...

[Code (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbW18.png)

```
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Pipes;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    internal class NamedPipes
    {
        public static string luapipename = "IDUNNOPIPE123";

        public static void LuaPipe(string script)
        {
            if (NamedPipeExist(luapipename))
            {
                new Thread (delegate {
                    try
                    {
                        using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", luapipename, PipeDirection.Out))
                        {
                            stream.Connect();
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Default, 0xf423f))
                            {
                                writer.Write(script);
                                writer.Dispose();
                            }
                            stream.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error occured connecting to the pipe.", "Connection Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exception1.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }).Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Inject " + Functions.exploitdllname + " before Using this!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        public static bool NamedPipeExist(string pipeName)
        {
            bool flag;
            try
            {
                int timeout = 0;
                if (!WaitNamedPipe(Path.GetFullPath($"\\\\.\\pipe\\{pipeName}"), timeout))
                {
                    bool flag4;
                    int num2 = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (num2 != 0)
                    {
                        if (num2 != 2)
                        {
                            goto TR_0005;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag4 = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag4 = false;
                    }
                    return flag4;
                }
            TR_0005:
                flag = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;
        }

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern bool WaitNamedPipe(string name, int timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it tell you is wrong -- can't help if we don't know the problem

Comment: This can't be the "full code" since no code starts with `{`  where is the rest?

Comment: Hover over the error, what does it say?

Comment: I hovered over it. This is the result (sry its german): http://prntscr.com/mt6686

Comment: @Hogan There is no rest. Just one line with the namespace definition (namespace InjectionTool)

Comment: It looks like it says there is no function with that parameter

Comment: The error tries to tell me that Visual Studio cant decide between "Thread.Thread(ThreadStart)" and "Thread.Thread(ParametizedThreadStart)".

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Thread.Thread(ThreadStart)' and 'Thread.Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart)'` error with this.

As you correctly noted, the compiler can't distinguish what type the `Thread` constructor parameter is. [ParameterizedThreadStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=netframework-4.7.2) is used if you pass a parameter to your delegate when calling the `Thread.Start` method. Your code does not do this. Thus, you need a [ThreadStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstart?view=netframework-4.7.2) delegate here. Its syntax is

```
public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

I.e. it does not accept any parameter and does not return a value. So, you can just pass a [lambda function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) that does the same.

```
new Thread(() => {
    // ...
}).Start();
```

Comment: I fixed everything and my program is almost good to go. But now i got another problem: The resource identifier "Identifier" has already been used in this assembly. I get this error 2 times if i try to build the project. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Alright. Solved Everything. Anyways, thanks a lot :)!